# How can I return the average of all unique values of ages with an OpenCypher query in Apache AGE

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm dealing with a project where I want to return the average value of all unique ages, for example users` ages are [20,30,50,20,20,20], the average of unique ages will be (20+30+50)/3.

I used **avg()** function, but it doesn't solve the problem, it returns the average of all values including duplicates.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN avg(n.age)
$$) as (avg agtype);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT keyword inside the aggregate function

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN avg(DISTINCT n.age)
$$) as (avg_age agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT to get only unique values, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    WITH DISTINCT n.age AS age
    RETURN avg(age)
$$) as (avg agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by "DISTINCT" clause(as answered above/below). One other way to achieve the same is by sub query.

Here's a way to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT AVG(age) AS average FROM (SELECT DISTINCT age FROM "yourtable") AS unique;
```

*Change accordingly for cypher queries*

Answer (score 0):

Try with "WITH AND DISTINCT"

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$ MATCH (n:Person) WITH DISTINCT n.age AS age RETURN avg(age) AS averageAge $$) AS AVG_AGE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT keyword to for unique values

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN avg(UNWIND collect(DISTINCT n.age) as age RETURN age)
$$) as (avg agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT avg(DISTINCT n.age) AS avg_age FROM cypher('test', 
$$
    MATCH (n:Person)
    RETURN n.age
$$
) AS (n agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of tackling this issue would be to use a subquery to extract the distinct ages first and then use a separate piece of code to calculate the average. Here's how it can be done:

```
SELECT AVG(age) AS average_unique_age
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT n.age
    FROM cypher('test', $$
        MATCH (n:Person)
        RETURN n.age
    $$) AS (age INT)
) AS unique_ages;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update your query like

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name_here', $$ 
 MATCH (n:Person)
RETURN avg(distinct n.age) 
$$) as (avg agtype)
```

By doing Distinct you can get you desired Output

Answer (score -1):

In the query you wrote `avg` function will return the average of all items in the list even if there are duplicates they will be considered while computing the average So, the output of the query you wrote will be as follow :

```
avg = (20+30+50+20+20+20 ) / 6 = 26.67
```

If you want to only consider unique values in the list than you should use `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplicates as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.cypher('graph_name', $$
 MATCH (n:Person)
 WITH DISTINCT n.age AS unique_age
 RETURN avg(unique_age)
 $$)
AS (result agtype);
```

Note that `WITH DISTINCT n.age AS unique_age` will filter out duplicated items.
So, now the output of the query will be as follows:

```
avg = (20+30+50) / 3 = 33.3
```

Only unique items will be used to compute the average of the list.